# Undefined Class and Expected A Class Member

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

I'm tearing my hair out - I'm sure I'm missing something small, but I can't see it for the life of me! Any hints really appreciated. Essentially on the line `root.name = 'root';` it's giving me the following errors:

`Undefined Class 'root.name'` on the 'root.name' section
`Expected a Class Member` on the '=' sign.

```
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

class AppLogic {

  Item root = new Item();

  root.name = 'root';

  List<Item> allItems;

  void createNewItem(Item parent){
    allItems.add(new Item());
  }
}

class Item {
  DateTime created = DateTime.now();
  String name;
  String ID = new Uuid().v1();

  Item parentID;
  List<String> childrenIDs;

  Item.fromID(this.ID);
  Item.fromName(this.name);
  Item();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is not allowed outside a constructor or method

```
  root.name = 'root';
```

Only variable declaration (with initialization), method declaration, and constructors are allowed in a class' body.

You could do it like

```
class AppLogic {

  Item root = new Item()..name = 'root';

  List<Item> allItems;

  void createNewItem(Item parent){
    allItems.add(new Item());
  }
}
```

Comment: Argh! I knew i was being daft... Thank you!